# Помогите решить пример с оператором for

Tags: c++

Помогите решить этот пример: ***y=cos(1+cos(2+...+cos(39+cos40)...)).***

Не знаю что положить в цикл.

Программа на с++.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/756392

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double y = 0;
    for(int i=40; i>=1; i--) {
        y = cos(i + y);
    }
    cout << y;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
double res = cos(40.0);
for(double x = 39; x > 0.5; x = x - 1)
    res = cos(x + res);
```